# Finding the population given the average, the median and the interquantil range. 15Yo homework question.

Tags: statistics

My 15y old little brother had a math homework that I failed to solve.

In the table below :
    1/.  The average is 1.5
    2/.  The Median is 2
    3/.  The interquantil range is 5

```
Value              -1    0    2    4        Total
Population          ?    ?    ?    ?          20
                    a    b    c    d
```

My deduction are :

basic:
=> a+b+c+d =20
a in {0,20}, b in {0,20}, c in {0,20}, d in {0,20}.

1/.
=> (-1 * a + 0 * b + 2 * c + 4 * d)/20 = 1.5

2/. The median cut the population in half. The 10th element must be in c.
=> a+b < 10  &&  a+b+c >= 10

3/. Q1 = -1 and Q3 = 4, are the only values that solve Q3-Q1 = 5.
Q1 is at least 25% of the population, and Q3 75%.
=> a >= 5 && a+b+c < 15

From this point I have no basic math  nor  simple trick to find the solution.
So I did brute force every possible value to see if I could find an obvious solution. 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/H6PCln

But this is not a mathematical solution.
So I must be missing something obvious or I'm wrong about something:

Using basic math is there a way to solve this problem?

[image: picture of the question as reference.]

Answer (score 1):

A helpful idea here is to take into consideration that we deal with observed values in a population, hence, $a,b,c,d$ must be natural numbers.

You have already found $Q_1=-1$ and $Q_3=4$, because the interquartile range must be less than or equal to the range of the data which is equal to $5$.

- Since $Q_1=-1$, you know that data items $5$ and $6$ are equal to $-1$. Hence, there must be at least $6$ times the observation $-1$.
- Similarly, since $Q_3=4$, you know that data items $15$ and $16$ are equal to $4$. So, there must be at least $6$ times the observation $4$.
- Now, you use the average for these minimal values
  $$-6+0\cdot b + 2c+24=30 \Leftrightarrow c=6\Rightarrow b=2$$
  This gives a possible population of
  $$6\times (-1), 2\times 0, 6\times 2, 6\times 4$$

Note, that there is (at least) a second solution. So, the problem should only ask for a possible population.

$$8\times (-1), 1\times 0, 3\times 2, 8\times 4$$

Comment: Ho, I had Q1 is at least 25% of the population. But it's definition is the half of the first half! So 5 and 6. Given that the original homework is a oneliner with an empty table I didn't expect multiple solutions to be valid answers. I assume I missed something.

Comment: Do you see a valid way to get [  6 ;  3 ;  4 ;  7 ] and [  8 ;  0 ;  5 ;  7 ] without "brute forcing"?

Comment: I think my way to the first population is no brute force but using arguments about the quartiles and solving an equation. To find the other population, you can argue that $c$ must be natural and cannot be $10$, since the median is $2$. So, when solving $-a+2c+4d=30$, you rule out $a=7$ and $a=9$ and you only need to check $a=8$. And here it is in a sense brute force but in a very reduced way. :-)

Comment: @xdtTransform : There is another point. There are teachers out there who put problems without thinking them through carefully. Maybe this is the case here. Me too, I would not expect multiple solutions within such a problem setting.

Comment: The question was tagged as "défis", challenge in English. I will blame the lock lockdown, Teacher had limited time to craft online course and one difficult one slipped by.

Comment: Lucky that the teacher didn't ask for all solutions :-). But multiple solutions are ok if it is a challenge.